# System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

We have a system that we're moving from .NET Framework to .NET Core.

One piece of this is a logging system that we configure at startup using SimpleInjector. So in
App_Start\SimpleInjectorConfig we have:

```
private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
{
    var application = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.SiteName;
    var instance = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath;

    // .. use application and instance in configuring the logging system
}
```

And the problem, of course, is that in .NET Core there isn't any System.Web.Hosting.

I've been browsing around, and I haven't found a way of getting an equivalent to HostingEnvironment.SiteName in .NET Core - at startup, before any endpoints are active.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you checked these two Git tickets of .net core: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7400 and https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17069?

Comment: I had not seen those. Thank you for pointing them out.

It may be we need to reconsider whether we actually need these.

Comment: welcome. please consider mentioning what alternative solution you have taken.

Answer (score 2):

Check the discussion around SiteName on these two .net Core Git tickets. and that will help you to take the decision weather it is really required.

```
github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7400 and 
github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17069
```